# Updating item in DynamoDB fails for the UpdateExpression syntax

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My table data looks like below one

```
{
  "id": {
    "S": "alpha-rocket"
  },
  "images": {
    "SS": [
      "apple/value:50",
      "Mango/aa:284_454_51.0.0",
      "Mango/bb:291",
      "Mango/cc:4"
    ]
  },
  "product": {
    "S": "fruit"
  }
}
```

Below is my code to update table. The variables I am passing to function has values `product_id` has `alpha-rocket`, `image_val` has `284_454_53.0.0` and `image` has `Mango/aa:284_454_53.0.0`.
I am trying to update value of `Mango/aa` from `284_454_51.0.0` to `284_454_53.0.0` but getting an error "The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update"

```
def update_player_score(product_id, image_val, image):  
    dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb')  
    tbl = dynamo.Table('<TableName>')  

    result = tbl.update_item(
          expression_attribute_names: {
            "#image_name" => "image_name"
          },
          expression_attribute_values: {
            ":image_val" => image_val,
          },
          key: {
            "product" => "fruit",
            "id" => product_id,
          },
          return_values: "ALL_NEW",
          table_name: "orcus",
          update_expression: "SET images.#image_val = :image_val",
        }
```

Is there a way to update the value of `Mango/aa` or replace full string `"Mango/aa:284_454_51.0.0"` to `"Mango/aa:284_454_53.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update a string in a list by matching the string. If you know the index of it you can replace the value of the string by index:

```
SET images[1] = : image_val
```

It seems like maybe what you want is not a list of strings, but another map. So instead of your data looking like it does you'd make it look like this, which would allow you to do the update you're looking for:

```
{
  "id": {
    "S": "alpha-rocket"
  },
  "images": {
    "M": {
      "apple" : {
        "M": {
          "value": {
            "S": "50"
          }
      },
      "Mango" : {
        "M": {
          "aa": {
            "S": "284_454_51.0.0"
          },
          "bb": {
            "S": "291"
          },
          "cc": {
            "S": "4"
          }
      }
    }
  },
  "product": {
    "S": "fruit"
  }
}
```

I would also consider putting the different values in different "rows" in the table and using queries to build the objects.